# How to handle large set of Json Data in MVC?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

How to handle large set of JsonData?
The data I'm returning contains 200k+ rows.

I've already set the web config file to the ff.

```
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Ive also added the key.

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647 " />
```

The problem is when I put a break point on the jsonResult it returns the rows but I'm getting an error on the browser saying that **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**.

Heres my code on the controller

```
    var jsonResult = Json(listofParticipant);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return jsonResult;
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried to use `Stream` so that the result will not sit in memory still I'm getting `OutOfMemoryException`

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\json.txt"))
            {
                using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, listofParticipant);
                }
            }

            var xserializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\json.txt"))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var xx = xserializer.Deserialize<List<PatricipantSearchViewModel>>(jsonTextReader);
                return Json(xx, "application/json", Encoding.Default, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
```

I also added this code based on the answers here in SO.

```
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
        MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.Net or StackOverflow's JSON deserializer and instead of returining JsonResult try returning text?

Comment: Yeah I've tried JSON.Net but still it returns System.OutOfMemoryException when serializing list with 200k rows

Comment: That is a lot of data, and will end up with a lot of memory used. Do you have the ability to "page" the data?

Answer (score 0):

add the following in the web.config and see if this solves your problem.

```
 <system.webServer>  
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```